# How to move a div to the center of the screen, irrespective of screen size?

Tags: html, css

I have a html code:

```css
#table{
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 2px solid black;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

#qrtr_details{
    margin: auto;
    width: 80%;
    padding: 5px;
    overflow: auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div>
        <div id="table">
            <table id="qrtr_details" border="1">
                <tr style="padding: 5px;">
                    <td><b>Employee No/Name:</b></td>
                    <td><input type="text" size="30" id="emp" maxlength="11" style="text-align: center;"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I want to re-position the div `#table` to the center of the screen.

But the div is centered horizontally, and not vertically. How do I fix this?

Comment: The faster way to set **height & line-height** as the same value, such as `#table{ height: 500px ; line-height: 500px }`

Comment: you can use flexbox properties to align a div to center you can refer here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/